# Calling outside method inside a VUE.JS component

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I want to ask you if it is possible, inside a VUE.JS component 'A', to call a method of another VUE.JS component 'B' that uses component 'A'.

Thank you

Comment: Do you mean you you want to run a method from a child component in the parent component? There's a few ways of doing that, I usually access the child component's methods by setting a ref, afterwards you get access to the components scope via this.$refs['component name']

Comment: I want to run a method of the parent component in the child component

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using $emit. https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html

For example say your child componet has a delete button to delete it from the parent page:

```html
<span title="remove" v-on:click="$emit('delete')">x</span>
```

Here I have used v-on:click to emit a custom event up to the parent component. https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html

In the parent component we listen for this event and run some function defined there when the event occurs:

```html
<your-componet @delete="removeMe"/>
```

(@ is shorthand for the v-on: directive)

In your methods prop in the parent componet you would define the removeMe function:

```js
methods :{
  removeMe () {
   // code to delete
  }
}
```